# Using neutral as common on a 3-way switch

Tags: electrical

I have an old home and have a light fixture with a switched neutral. There is no junction box. There are only two black cloth wires hanging from my ceiling. I have verified the neutral wire is switched. I guess this is how it used to be done, and has been working just fine. There is no access to the circuit to 'fix' it. I realize the fixture is always hot and will take care to flip the breaker before changing a bulb. [image: Existing Switched Neutral Circuit]

I am wondering if it is safe to add 3 way switches to this circuit, by taking a typical "dead end 3-way" configuration and using the neutral line as the common from both new switches instead of the hot. In this way the 3-way mechanical switching occurs on the neutral conductor instead of the hot- which is essentially what I already have with the single pole switching the neutral.

Would there be anything wrong here- or at least any worse than what I already have?

My understanding is the switched neutral portion of the circuit is as safe a switched hot- it is the always energized fixture that is a problem.

[image: Proposed 3-Way using switched neutral instead of hot]

Comment: You have drawn the neutral wire as running directly from the switch to the service panel. Doesn't it pass through the light fixture junction box?

Comment: The light fixture does not have a junction box. There are two bare wires from the ceiling, one is hot, and the other is a neutral goes to the switch. I have verified this with a multimeter. I have not traced the wire, but I assume the neural eventually terminates at my panel.

Comment: You need to break this down into two separate questions. The first is fixing the switched neutral problem. Once, and only once you have that problem fixed is it time to think about updating the circuit. _Technically_, if this is original work and done prior to implementation of electrical code preventing this, it's grandfathered in, but the moment you touch it, you're required to bring it to current code. Of course, this is a dangerous situation and you should do so whether required to or not.

Comment: Please [register](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: See also this discussion https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/switched-neutral-and-voltage.746757/#post-6853983

Answer (score 3):

Edit: TLDR: **Moot point since ungrounded circuits cannot be extended**.  I would suggest using a smart switch which doesn't require neutral (trick though: most of those require ground - shop carefully)... and that supports a wireless remote (truly wireless; the remote takes batteries).  Then simply affix the remote to your desired location. Some remotes can be installed in a junction box like a normal switch, in that case feel free to install an empty plastic junction box, and there you could use an orange un-box since no wires attach.

Original:

> I have an old home and have a light fixture with a switched neutral. I guess this is how it used to be done,, and has been working just fine.

In electrical, lots of arrangements work, and then kill you.

> here is no access to the circuit to 'fix' it.

That seems unlikely. Have you actually checked?  Almost certainly, power comes to the lamp *in a cable* and then runs from lamp to switch in another cable.  That would mean that the white wires are spliced to each other inside the lamp box.  This splice can be undone.  Turn off the switch and remove the bulb, then probe to identify supply hot.  If it's on a black wire going to the lamp, then yeah, that's a switched neutral all right.

- Identify the supply neutral (partner to the supply hot). Unsplice it and attach it to lamp neutral.  You won't deal with this wire again.
- Splice supply black/hot to switch loop white - **this is a Code requirement**.
- Connect switch loop black to the hot wire on the lamp.

At this point your lamp isn't switched neutral anymore.

You can then proceed in the normal fashion.  When white isn't neutral, it must be used as always-hot, but never for switched-hot.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the circuit with a multimeter. There is no junction box and no splices at the light. There are two black cloth insulated cables coming from the ceiling at the light. One is hot and one is a neutral that is switched at the wall.

Comment: I don't there are any cables involved at all from the sounds of it. It could be as simple as switching the landing points in the panel of the two individual, otherwise unmarked wires, but I don't know if that's kosher, and it could cause issues elsewhere if this is _not_ the only device on the circuit.

Comment: @CoreyB A "cable" is multiple "wires" wrapped in a sheath.  If I interpret your words correctly there are no cables at all, only single wires coming out of the ceiling, and you probably have a knob-and-tube type installation.  **It's very hard to be sure about hot vs neutral in this type of installation**.  The only way to get a solid ground reference is to find a grounded location e.g. a main panel with modern ground rods, and run a wire from there as a reference.

Comment: Thank you. I am very very sure that this is a switched neutral. I have used a known good multimeter with a known good ground. You are correct - there are only two black cloth wires hanging from my ceiling.  Also can reverify that there is no junction box with any sort of accessible splices at the light fixture. Just two old black wires.

Answer (score 3):

Not impossible; the cloth insulation may mean the wiring is old enough to predate code...

If the entire circuit is backward, this could be fixed and the breaker/fuse box. That's a job best left for someone who knows what they're doing.

Otherwise you could try to find an upstream box or fixture where the mistake occurred and exchange the hot and neutral feeds there to fix it.

Otherwise, it may be time to consider pulling new wire for this circuit so it can conform to modern code.

If none of those are acceptable, I suspect a pro would refuse the job. The last person to modify a circuit is often considered to own the liability for not correcting an obvious problem...

Comment: Most places, this sort of job would require permit and inspection, which clearly is not going to pass. Neutral switching has been forbidden for well over a century in the U.S. No legitimate tradesman would touch this.